# Thinking_sphinx starts but rake still fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, thinking-sphinx

I am using Rails 3.0.7 and the Thinking_sphinx 2.0.13.

Background:

I'm trying to create a deploy script (capistrano) where sphinx will be stoped before capistrano updates the code, and then started again when the update is done.

However, the rake task for thinking_sphinx:start fails.

The commands below are run in this exact order.

```
$ rake thinking_sphinx:stop

Stopped search daemon (pid 54117).
searchd is not running
```

```
$ ps aux | grep searchd
xx  54597   0.0  0.0  2434892    532 s002  R+    4:04PM   0:00.00 grep searchd
```

```
$ rake thinking_sphinx:start
Started successfully (pid 54618).
rake aborted!
searchd is already running.

Tasks: TOP => thinking_sphinx:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

```
$ ps aux | grep searchd
xx  54637   0.8  0.0  2434892    448 s002  R+    4:06PM   0:00.00 grep searchd
xx  54618   0.0  0.0  2442992    396 s002  S     4:05PM   0:00.02 searchd --pidfile --config /Users/emil/code/wd/config/development.sphinx.conf
```

So yes, it starts but the rake task fails. When I run these commands in "cap deploy", capistrano will rollback my updated code because the rake task fails.

How do I solve this? I have no ideas left.

Comment: same problem here, did you ever find a solution?